# Assigning objects to an array, then call it from the array based on position

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've been working on this code but am puzzled as to why it doesn't work. I've created three "*Geocache*" objects and assigned them to an array called '*caches*'. To test, I've assigned the variable "*value*" to whatever is in index 1 of *caches*. I then defined the variable "*tease*" as the '*lony*' property of *value*.

```html
function Geocache (lat, lon, disc){
  this.laty=lat;
  this.lony=lon;
  this.disc=disc;
}

  
var loc1=new Geocache(43.77416104496804, -79.50804830784301, "lifesci building");
var loc2=new Geocache(43.77381242916627, -79.50533927673797, "lassonde building");
var loc3=new Geocache(43.77305321438563, -79.50353146786193, "vari hall");
var caches=[loc1,loc2,loc3];

var value = caches[1];
var tease=value.lony;
```

This should spit back the value of "-79.505..." but instead I get an "undefined" in the preview. 
Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with this code because I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: On chrome it failing because it's seems to clashing with -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/caches  And this is read only.   So your `var caches'  actually equals  window.caches..  Place you code inside self invoking function,.. to stop your vars polluting the global window object.   PS.. edit your code snippet, and put your javascript code in the javascript section ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you code, with the javascript in the javascript part of the snippet.

And a fix to use a self invoking function to stop global leak.

```js
function Geocache (lat, lon, disc){
  this.laty=lat;
  this.lony=lon;
  this.disc=disc;
}

(function () {  
  var loc1=new Geocache(43.77416104496804, -79.50804830784301, "lifesci building");
  var loc2=new Geocache(43.77381242916627, -79.50533927673797, "lassonde building");
  var loc3=new Geocache(43.77305321438563, -79.50353146786193, "vari hall");
  var caches=[loc1,loc2,loc3];

  var value = caches[1];
  var tease=value.lony;
  console.log(tease);
})();
```